# FPDF arroja errores en localhost

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, localhost

> tengo este error al tratar de mostrar el pdf de reporteproductos.php, este hace un include a plantilla.php y platilla.php requiere de fpdf.php para mostrar el reporte, todo esta corriendo en localhost, hace tiempo tuve el mismo error en  000webhost y se soluciono al darle permisos 644, pero no se como solucionarlo en esta ocasion.

```
   Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 580

    Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 580

    Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 580

    Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 580

    Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(1063): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\reportedispo.php(56): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIGEF\modelo\pdf\fpdf\fpdf.php on line 271
```

> Este es el codigo en plantilla.php

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
        function Header()
        {
            //$this->image('images/sen2.png', 10, 10,50);
            $this->Image('images/sen2.png' , 10, 10,50);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            $this->Cell(50,'','',0);
            $this->Cell(140,5,'BOUTIQUE MARIA FERNANDA',0,1,'R');
            $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
            $this->Cell(50,'','',0);
            $this->Cell(140,5,'NIT 900354851-5',0,1,'R');
            $this->Cell(50,'','',0);
            $this->Cell(140,5,'Hoy: '.date('d-m-Y').'',0,1,'R');
            $this->Cell(50,'','',0);
            $this->Cell(140,5,'Usuario|'.$_SESSION['usuario'].'',0,1,'R');
            $this->Ln(5);   

        }

        // function Footer()
        // {
        //  $this->SetY(-15);
        //  $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        //  $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

        // }
        function Footer()
        {
            //Footer de la pagina
            $this->SetY(-15);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
            $this->SetTextColor(128);
            $this->Cell(0,10,'Pagina '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
        }  
    }


?>
```

> este es reporteproductos.php y desde aqui se llama a plantilla para mostrar el reporte de productos:

```
<?php           
        include 'plantilla.php';
        require 'config.php';

        $sql="SELECT * FROM  tb_productos ORDER BY cod_producto ASC ";
        $resultado = $conexion->query( $sql );

        $pdf= new PDF();
        // $pdf->AliasNbPage();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Cell(120,10,'Reporte de Productos ',0,1,'L');
        $pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

        $pdf->Cell(25,6,'CODIGO',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(65,6,'NOMBRE',1,0,'C',1);

        $pdf->Cell(50,6,'PRECIO DE COMPRA',1,0,'C',1);
        $pdf->Cell(50,6,'FECHA DE REGISTRO',1,1,'C',1);

        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

        while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['cod_producto'],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(65,6,utf8_decode($row['descripcion']) ,1,0,'C');

            $pdf->Cell(50,6,$row['precio_compra'],1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(50,6,$row['fecha_registro'],1,1,'C');
        }

        $pdf->Output();

?>
```

De antemano gracias por su tiempo y colaboración, disculpen la molestia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es solo un `warning` una advertencia puedes silenciar los reportes y te funcionara perfectamente o si quieres puedes solucionarlo haciendo un cast:

> **Nota** esto se da porque en php +7 se hace un warning si la cadena pasada contiene un numero seguido de letras o contiene letras seguidas de numeros y se intenta tratar la variable como 1 u otra. es mejor espeficiarserla para corregir estos `warning`.

**ejemplo:**

`$result = is_numeric($_SESSION['usuario']) ? (int) $_SESSION['usuario'] : (string) $_SESSION['usuario']`;

REFERENCIA: [LINK](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php)

Comment: soy algo nuevo en esto, no se como hacer el cast, me podrías colaborar instruyéndome, gracias